# How to run unittest discover from "python setup.py test"?

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, pytest, unittest2

I'm trying to figure out how to get `python setup.py test` to run the equivalent of `python -m unittest discover`.  I don't want to use a run_tests.py script and I don't want to use any external test tools (like `nose` or `py.test`).  It's OK if the solution only works on python 2.7.

In `setup.py`, I think I need to add something to the `test_suite` and/or `test_loader` fields in config, but I can't seem to find a combination that works correctly:

```
config = {
    'name': name,
    'version': version,
    'url': url,
    'test_suite': '???',
    'test_loader': '???',
}
```

**Is this possible using only `unittest` built into python 2.7?**

FYI, my project structure looks like this:

```
project/
  package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_module.py
  run_tests.py <- I want to delete this
  setup.py
```

**Update**: This is possible with `unittest2` but I want find something equivalent using only `unittest`

From https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unittest2

> unittest2 includes a very basic setuptools compatible test collector. Specify test_suite = 'unittest2.collector' in your setup.py. This starts test discovery with the default parameters from the directory containing setup.py, so it is perhaps most useful as an example (see unittest2/collector.py).

For now, I'm just using a script called `run_tests.py`, but I'm hoping I can get rid of this by moving to a solution that only uses `python setup.py test`.

Here's the `run_tests.py` I'm hoping to remove:

```
import unittest

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # use the default shared TestLoader instance
    test_loader = unittest.defaultTestLoader

    # use the basic test runner that outputs to sys.stderr
    test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

    # automatically discover all tests in the current dir of the form test*.py
    # NOTE: only works for python 2.7 and later
    test_suite = test_loader.discover('.')

    # run the test suite
    test_runner.run(test_suite)
```

Comment: Just a word of caution to anyone who happens to come here. setup.py test is considered a code 'smell' and is also set to be deprecated. 

https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-runner/issues/50

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you use py27+ or py32+, the solution is pretty simple:

```
test_suite="tests",
```

Comment: I wish this worked better, I ran into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164004/python-package-structure-setup-py-for-running-unit-tests "Test names should match module names. If there is a "foo_test.py" test, there needs to be a corresponding module foo.py."

Comment: I agree.  In my case, where I'm testing a Python external where there literally is no such Python module with a .py, there seems to be no good way to achieve this.

Comment: This is the correct solution. I didn't have the issue @CharlesL. had. All my tests are named `test_*.py`. In addition I found out that it will actually recursively search through the given directory to find *any* class that extends `unittest.TestCast`. This is extremely useful if you have a directory structure where in you have `tests/first_batch/test_*.py` and `tests/second_batch/test_*.py`. You can just specify `test_suite="tests",` and it will pick up everything recursively. Note that each nested directory will need to have an `__init__.py` file in it.

Comment: You need to do `from setuptools import setup` instead of `from distutils.core import setup` for this option to exist. I don't know why official docs seems to use distutils.core, I guess that's the default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58534041 has a good description of this and other arguments.

Answer (score 41):

From [Building and Distributing Packages with Setuptools](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) (emphasis mine):

> test_suite
>
> A string naming a unittest.TestCase subclass (or a package or module
>   containing one or more of them, or a method of such a subclass), or naming 
>   **a function that can be called with no arguments and returns a unittest.TestSuite**.

Hence, in `setup.py` you would add a function that returns a TestSuite:

```
import unittest
def my_test_suite():
    test_loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    test_suite = test_loader.discover('tests', pattern='test_*.py')
    return test_suite
```

Then, you would specify the command `setup` as follows:

```
setup(
    ...
    test_suite='setup.my_test_suite',
    ...
)
```

Comment: There is a problem with this solution, because it creates 2 "levels" of unittest. Meaning that setuptools will create a 'test' command that will try to create a TestSuite from setup.my_test_suite, which will force it to import setup.py, which will run the setup() again! This second time it will create a new (nested) test command that runs your desired test. This might not be noticeable to most people, but if you try to extend the test command (I needed to modify it because I can't run my tests 'in-place') you might run into weird issues. Use https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726329/3272850 instead

Comment: This causes the tests to run twice for me for reasons mentioned above. Fixed it by moving the function into the `__init__.py` of the tests folder and referencing that.

Comment: The issue with tests being executed twice can be easily fixed by executing `setup()` function inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` block in `setup.py` script. The first time the setup script is being executed, so the if block will be called; the second time the setup script will be imported as a module, so the if block will not be called.

Comment: Hmm, I realize that my setup.py does NOT contain that `test_suite` parameter at all, yet "python setup.py test" still works fine for me. That is different that what [the docs says](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite): "If you did not set a test_suite in your setup() call, and do not provide a --test-suite option, an error will occur." Any idea?

Answer (score 20):

You don't need config to get this working. There are basically two main ways to do it:

**The quick way**

Rename your `test_module.py` to `module_test.py` (basically add `_test` as a suffix to tests for a particular module), and python will find it automatically. Just make sure to add this to `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    test_suite = 'tests',
    ...
)
```

**The long way**

Here's how to do it with your current directory structure:

```
project/
  package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_module.py
  run_tests.py <- I want to delete this
  setup.py
```

Under `tests/__init__.py`, you want to import the `unittest` and your unit test script `test_module`, and then create a function to run the tests. In `tests/__init__.py`, type in something like this:

```
import unittest
import test_module

def my_module_suite():
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = loader.loadTestsFromModule(test_module)
    return suite
```

The `TestLoader` class has other functions besides `loadTestsFromModule`. You can run `dir(unittest.TestLoader)` to see the other ones, but this one is the simplest to use.

Since your directory structure is such, you'll probably want the `test_module` to be able to import your `module` script. You might have already done this, but just in case you didn't, you could include the parent path so that you can import the `package` module and the `module` script. At the top of your `test_module.py`, type:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

import unittest
import package.module
...
```

Then finally, in `setup.py`, include the `tests` module and run the command you created, `my_module_suite`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    ...
    test_suite = 'tests.my_module_suite',
    ...
)
```

Then you just run `python setup.py test`.

Here is a [sample](https://github.com/ctb/SomePackage) someone made as a reference.

Comment: The question was how to make "python setup.py test" use unittest's discovery capability. This doesn't address that at all.

Comment: Ugh... yeah I completely thought the question was asking something different. I'm not sure how that happened, I must be losing my mind :(

Answer (score 6):

One possible solution is to simply extend the `test` command for `distutils`and `setuptools`/`distribute`.  This seems like a total kluge and way more complicated than I would prefer, but seems to correctly discover and run all the tests in my package upon running `python setup.py test`.  I'm holding off on selecting this as the answer to my question in hopes that someone will provide a more elegant solution :)

(Inspired by https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#integrating-with-setuptools-python-setup-py-test-pytest-runner)

Example `setup.py`:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

def discover_and_run_tests():
    import os
    import sys
    import unittest

    # get setup.py directory
    setup_file = sys.modules['__main__'].__file__
    setup_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(setup_file))

    # use the default shared TestLoader instance
    test_loader = unittest.defaultTestLoader

    # use the basic test runner that outputs to sys.stderr
    test_runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()

    # automatically discover all tests
    # NOTE: only works for python 2.7 and later
    test_suite = test_loader.discover(setup_dir)

    # run the test suite
    test_runner.run(test_suite)

try:
    from setuptools.command.test import test

    class DiscoverTest(test):

        def finalize_options(self):
            test.finalize_options(self)
            self.test_args = []
            self.test_suite = True

        def run_tests(self):
            discover_and_run_tests()

except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import Command

    class DiscoverTest(Command):
        user_options = []

        def initialize_options(self):
                pass

        def finalize_options(self):
            pass

        def run(self):
            discover_and_run_tests()

config = {
    'name': 'name',
    'version': 'version',
    'url': 'http://example.com',
    'cmdclass': {'test': DiscoverTest},
}

setup(**config)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another less than ideal solution slightly inspired by http://hg.python.org/unittest2/file/2b6411b9a838/unittest2/collector.py

Add a module that returns a `TestSuite` of discovered tests.  Then configure setup to call that module.

```
project/
  package/
    __init__.py
    module.py
  tests/
    __init__.py
    test_module.py
  discover_tests.py
  setup.py
```

Here's `discover_tests.py`:

```
import os
import sys
import unittest

def additional_tests():
    setup_file = sys.modules['__main__'].__file__
    setup_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(setup_file))
    return unittest.defaultTestLoader.discover(setup_dir)
```

And here's `setup.py`:

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

config = {
    'name': 'name',
    'version': 'version',
    'url': 'http://example.com',
    'test_suite': 'discover_tests',
}

setup(**config)
```

Answer (score 3):

Python's standard library `unittest` module supports discovery (in Python 2.7 and later, and Python 3.2 and later). If you can assume those minimum versions, then you can just add the `discover` command line argument to the `unittest` command.

Only a small tweak is needed to `setup.py`:

```python
import setuptools.command.test
from setuptools import (find_packages, setup)

class TestCommand(setuptools.command.test.test):
    """ Setuptools test command explicitly using test discovery. """

    def _test_args(self):
        yield 'discover'
        for arg in super(TestCommand, self)._test_args():
            yield arg

setup(
    ...
    cmdclass={
        'test': TestCommand,
    },
)
```

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming above that you're only targeting Python versions that actual support discovery (2.7 and 3.2+), since the question is about this feature specifically. You could, of course, wrap the insert in a version-check if you wanted to remain compatible with older versions, as well (thus using setuptools' standard loader in those cases).

Answer (score 0):

This won't remove run_tests.py, but will make it work with setuptools. Add:

```
class Loader(unittest.TestLoader):
    def loadTestsFromNames(self, names, _=None):
        return self.discover(names[0])
```

Then in setup.py: (I assume you're doing something like `setup(**config)`)

```
config = {
    ...
    'test_loader': 'run_tests:Loader',
    'test_suite': '.', # your start_dir for discover()
}
```

The only downside I see is it's bending the semantics of `loadTestsFromNames`, but the setuptools test command is the only consumer, and calls it in a [specified way](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#test-loader).