# Setuptools - how to run unittest test suite when tests are not in main directory?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, setuptools, python-unittest

I have a following module structure:

```
main
->module
--->tests
----->test_module.py
--->module.py
->setup.py
```

I have unit tests implemented using `unittest` package. When following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001010/how-to-run-unittest-discover-from-python-setup-py-test) I set my `setup.py` file to be:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='module',
    packages=['module', ],
    test_suite='module/tests',
)
```

Produced the following error message:

> ====================================================================== ERROR: tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in
>   loadTestsFromName
>       module = **import**(module_name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests/module'
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> FAILED (errors=1) Test failed:  error: Test failed:

When setting `test_suite='tests` I've got:

> ====================================================================== ERROR: tests (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError: Failed to import test module: tests Traceback (most
>   recent call last):   File
>   "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/unittest/loader.py", line 153, in
>   loadTestsFromName
>       module = **import**(module_name) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> FAILED (errors=1) Test failed:  error: Test failed:

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test_suite` is the name of the test **package** (in Python dotted syntax), not directory path, so the syntax must be

```
test_suite='module.tests',
```