# How to organize my tests in different folders in Python with setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to divide my tests up into seperate folders so that they are organized. I tried a couple of things but it seems like it can't find my test.

The structure looks like this

```
-- root
   -- setup.py
   -- docs
   -- src
   -- tests
      -- __init__.py
      -- defaultTest.py
      -- DirA
         -- testA.py
      -- DirB
         -- testB.py
```

So I want to run testA but it can't find the module. I also tried to add a **init**.py file but that didn't work I'm able to launch the defaultTest.py however with python setup.py test -s tests.defaultTest but not the other ones.

My setup.py file looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages


with open('README') as f:
    readme = f.read()

setup(
    name='ringring',
    version='0.1.0',
    description='Sample package for Python-Guide.org',
    long_description=readme,
    url='',
    license=license,
    packages=find_packages(exclude=('tests', 'docs')),
    tests_require=['nose'],
    test_suite='tests',
)
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for reading!

Comment: What is in your `init.py` file?

Comment: the init file of the test folder is empty, do you think I should import the two folder underneath?

Comment: It's just an educated guess after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001010/how-to-run-unittest-discover-from-python-setup-py-test

Comment: especially this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23307488/1866177

Comment: Ok I did somewhat what you told me. I added a context file which returns the absolute url and did an import of it and that seems to work. I still need to figure out how it exactly works. Anyway thanks for the tip!